# Google Content Experiments and A/B Testing Strategies

Tags: conversion

We are wanting to start implementing A/B testing on various areas of sites. This may range from design/template changes to configuration settings. Most of the time, it's going to be tracking what impact a change has on conversion rates. Particularly we wanted to use Google Content Experiments to track this.

I haven't had much experience doing it before, so I'm interested in how we'd go about implementing the code and the best strategies for testing (I understood you can only accurately test changes in isolation). For example, on a template change do we make all of the changes in one template and show/hide what's necessary or should we be setting it at a higher level before the rendering happens?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Hey by the way, one of the reasons that I didn't use Google Content Experiments is because Wider Funnel said that they saw that the data was inaccurate and even Google admitted it apparently.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hy5qRf4UeO8 - so I just went with a very simple approach using Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off, I wanted to mention that you might want to check out https://www.store-optimizer.com/ - it's a really interesting project for A/B testing on Magento.  I haven't used it myself but it looks pretty awesome.  Especially since you mentioned that you're wanting to test things like configuration changes.

One of the important considerations for me when building MageSplit was that I needed the test to be done on the javascript side.  We use Varnish and FPC, so I wouldn't be able to handle the rendering in PHP, which would of course give you a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Hi Kalen, thanks for the link that does look very interesting. Given what you've said about Google Content Experiments, this might be an easier way to go for the client to monitor things. I'll take a look at your module too.

Answer (score 3):

[@kalenjordan just build a small tool for this](https://twitter.com/kalenjordan/status/378312861384069120)

[Magesplit](https://github.com/kalenjordan/magesplit) is a small javascript library to do small and easy A/B testing with utilizing google analytics and can be downloaded from github.